# Meteor: retrieving and inserting subdocuments

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I can't seem to get the data for the ingredients array and insert into mongodb. Anyone have any ideas?

Error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

My form event on client:

```
Template.newRecipe.events({
  'submit form'(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get value from form element
    const target = event.target;
    const title = target.title.value;
    const description = target.description.value;
    const ingredients = target.ingredients.value; // line causing above error

    // Insert a task into the collection
    Meteor.call('recipes.insert', title, description, ingredients);
    document.getElementById('insertRecipeForm').reset();
  },
});
```

My server Method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'recipes.insert'(title, description, ingredients) {
    Recipes.insert({
      title,
      description,
      ingredients,
    });
  },
});
```

My schema:

```
Recipes = new Mongo.Collection('recipes');

Ingredient = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  amount: {
    type: String
  }
});

Recipe = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title"
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    label: "Description",
    autoform: {
        rows: 6
    }
  },
  ingredients: {
    type: [Ingredient]
  }
});

Recipes.attachSchema(Recipe);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not inserting an object:

```
Recipes.insert({
  title,
  description,
  ingredients,
});
```

Needs to be:

```
Recipes.insert({
  title: title,
  description: description,
  ingredients: {$push: ingredients},
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michel, unfortunately though I'm still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that target.ingredients doesn't exist for some reason. Without seeing your HTML we probably can't offer any better advice than that.